# WebSharper's Enhance.WithResetAction

Tags: f#, websharper

I built a WebSharper formlet using the combinators, but my goal is to embed it in a jQueryUI pop-up. As a consequence I need to be able to close the dialog when the user clicks no, the following doesn't work:

```
let confirmationForm order =
    let title = DialogConfiguration(Title = "Are you sure you want to place the order?")
    let form = Formlet.Return ()
                |> Enhance.WithCustomSubmitAndResetButtons
                    { Enhance.FormButtonConfiguration.Default with Label = Some "Yes" }
                    { Enhance.FormButtonConfiguration.Default with Label = Some "No" }
                |> Enhance.WithFormContainer
    let rec dialog = Dialog.New(Div [ result ], title)
    and result =
        Formlet.Do {
            let! _ = form |> Enhance.WithResetAction (fun _ -> dialog.Close(); true)
            dialog.Close()
            return Server.SubmitOrder order
        } |> Enhance.WithFormContainer

    (dialog :> IPagelet).Render()

Formlet.Do {
    let! order = orderForm
    return confirmationForm order
}
|> Enhance.WithFormContainer
```

The dialog closes fine on clicking yes. Also I don't understand the signature requiring me to provide a function that returns true, that is kind of confusing as I do not need to supply any other callback.

Also, note that I am positively surprised that it supports mutually recursive function to allow to provide the workflow to the Dialog's Div. I'm assuming there would be a better way to do this though?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generalized function for displaying any formlet inside a jQueryUI Dialog:

```
[<JavaScript>]
let InDialog (title: string) (formlet: Formlet<'T>) =
    Formlet.BuildFormlet <| fun _ ->
        let state = new Event<_>()
        let conf =
            JQueryUI.DialogConfiguration (
                Modal = true,
                DialogClass = "dialog",
                Title = title
            )
        let dialogOpt : ref<option<JQueryUI.Dialog>> = 
            ref None
        let el =
            Div [
                formlet
                |> Formlet.Run (fun confirmed ->
                    match dialogOpt.Value with
                    | Some dialog ->
                        state.Trigger (Result.Success confirmed)
                        dialog.Close()
                    | None ->
                        ()
                )
            ]
        let dialog = 
            JQueryUI.Dialog.New(el, conf)
        dialogOpt := Some dialog
        Div [dialog] , ignore , state.Publish
```

And an example of using it:

```
[<JavaScript>]
let Main () =
    Formlet.Do {
        let! _ =  Controls.Button "Display Form"
        let! name = 
            Controls.Input ""
            |> Enhance.WithSubmitAndResetButtons "Submit" "Reset"
            |> InDialog "Enter your name" 
        return ()
    }
```

Regarding your question about the Boolean return value. I assume you are referring to Enhance.WithResetAction. The value determines whether the formlet is reset or not, after performing the action.

Comment: Thanks, your version is better encapsulated, but your reset button doesn't close the dialog - just like mine.